# How can I define a Schema and the express router in MERN stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

i need to work with a mongodb record like this one:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c09ae281646e8d8bad07d73"
    },
    "name": "somename",
    "genre": "somegenre",
    "indexes": {
        "index1": 1,
        "index2": 7,
        "index3": 7,
        "index4": 7,
        "index5": 7,
        "index6": 7,
        "index7": 7,
        "index8": 7,
        "index9": 7,
        "index10": 7,
        "index11": 7,
        "index12": 9,
        "index13": 5,
        "index14": 15,
        "index15": 8,
        "index16": 17
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": "2018-12-06T23:18:00.532Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

And them i set the Schema for mongoose like this

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  genre: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  indexes: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
    properties: {
      index1: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index2: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index3: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index4: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index5: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index6: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index7: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index8: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index9: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index10: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index11: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index12: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index13: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index14: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index15: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      index16: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }
  },
```

them my router post (express)

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name,
    genre: req.body.genre,
    indexes: {
      index1: req.body.indexes.index1,
      index2: req.body.indexes.index2...
```

them the inputs to set the index values (where im using the name property to defined how i will set the new item):

```
  <input
    type="text"
    name="indexes.index1"
    placeholder="sample 1"
    onChange={this.onChange}
  />
```

and the functions

```
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

and

```
onSubmit = e => {    
    const newItem = {
      name: this.state.name,
      genre: this.state.genre,
      indexes: {
        index1: this.state.indexes.index1,
...
```

the result them in the MongoDB is:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c0c22d41e3d5115dda930aa"
    },
    "name": "name",
    "genre": "somegen",
    "indexes": {
        "index1": "",
        "index2": ""
```

no values in the indexes
Any idea? suggestions?

Thanks guys.
Seba

Comment: Can you be more specific on "having issues when i tried to create a new item"? What happens exactly?

Comment: yes of course, when i tried to set the value of one of the indexes from a input form i use the name: indexes.index1 but not work when them i create a new item

Comment: Do you have an output of your `req.body` right before `new Item()`? You can add that to the question, it will be very helpful. Something like `console.log( req.body )` right before `const newItem ...` will do it.

Comment: yes, i added in the original question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your `setState` ReactJS call.

```
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

The `target.name` is always a string, so what you are doing is that you are setting a property with a key that contains a `.` ( `indexes.index1` ), so your state after `onChange` event would look like :

```
state = {
    "name": "name",
    "genre": "somegen",
    "indexes.index1": "1",
    "indexes.index2": "2",
    ...
}
```

This is not being recognised by `express`, and your request fails to deliver the proper body.

You can achieve what you want by having the indexes somehow converted to an object. Simplest way with your setup would be :

```
onChange = e => {

    if ( e.target.name.indexOf( "indexes" ) === 0 ) {
        this.setState({ indexes: Object.assign( this.state.indexes || {}, {
            [e.target.name.replace(/^indexes\./, "")]: e.target.value
        } ) } );
    } else {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
};
```

If your application structure allows, you can move the inputs that define the indexes in another component that would have as a callback the whole `indexN` object. This will help you to simply update the state without having to parse the index key.

Comment: Now is working, i just change the onChange with your suggestion and is working ok